# In the mousedown event, is it possible to cancel the resulting click event? or pass info to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

for arcane reasons I need to be able to cancel the click event via the mousedown event.

Briefly; I am creating a context menu in the mousedown event, however, when the user clicks on the page the context menu should disappear.

I am not able to use the mousedown event over the click in that scenario as I want the user to be able to click links inside the menu ( a full click would never travel to the `<a>` based menu elements ).

If it is any help, jQuery can be applied.

I would like to either be able to prevent the click event from happening from within the initial mousedown, or be able to pass information to the click event (via originalEvent or otherwise).

TIA

Comment: perhaps you could provide some `//example code` to encourage accurate feedback?  Thanks.

Comment: the jsfiddle base provided by user759588 seems fairly representative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had the exact same problem. I fixed my context menu by closing it on `mousedown` and eating the `mousedown` event on the menu so that I can still receive clicks on the menu, like so:

```
$(document).one('mousedown.ct', null, function() { cmenu.hide(); return false; });
cmenu.bind('mousedown', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
```

And in the `hide()` function I unbind the `mousedown.ct` again, in case it was closed due to a click on an item.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be impossible, neither FF nor Opera didnt cancel upcoming `click` when prevented in `mousedown` and/or `mouseup` (as side note: click is dispatched after mouseup if certain conditions met). testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/ksaeU/

Comment: I don't care who did what to whom, but folks tit for tat comments and revenge downvoting is not becoming of either your. Please be nice. :)

Comment: @Kev♦, just FYI, "don't care" part of "please be nice" call was kinda rude.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I think this is what you are trying to do with your code. If not, I apologize, I may have misunderstood the question. I used jQuery to get it done: http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/KArRD/

```
$('a').bind({
    mousedown: function(){
        // Do stuff
    },
    click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```